# Error en con mi jQuery no Envía ni recibe datos

Tags: jquery, ajax, bootstrap

Tengo un problema con mi `.js` ya que quiero hacer un conexión a un sitio desde otro pero envía la información porque pasa eso aquí dejo el link del plugin.

```
<script
  src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.js"
  integrity="sha256-DZAnKJ/6XZ9si04Hgrsxu/8s717jcIzLy3oi35EouyE="
  crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
    <a data-toggle="modal" data-target="#view-modal-embed" data-id="19352670814" id="getChatembed">
        <img class="bottom_chat_open" src="http://hooo.io/img/avatar_default.png">
    </a>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://hooo.io/js/embed.js"></script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Si pudieras dar más contexto o código de la situación, podría ayudarte de alguna manera. Saludos.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Tienes un problema de `Control de acceso HTTP (CORS)`

Que se refiere básicamente a la seguridad que tiene tu servidor para recibir datos de orignes no permitidos.
[Revisa la documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)

En tu caso debes configurar tu servidor donde recibes la petición para permitir el dominio desde donde haces la solicitud, la configuración depende del lenguaje que usas.